# while executing store procedure getting error

Tags: java, exception, procedures

I have written a calling procedure but an exception is being thrown, please can you look at my code:

```
try 
{   
    connection myconn = Database.Get_Connection();
    CallableStatement mystmt =null;
    mystmt = myconn.prepareCall("{? =call proc_hi_check_user(?,?)}");
    mystmt.setString(1,name);
    mystmt.setString(2,"");
    mystmt.execute();
    param1 = mystmt.getInt(1);
    ResultSet myrs = mystmt.getResultSet();
    while(myrs.next())
    {
        System.out.println("inside");
        System.out.println(myrs.getInt(1));
        //result=myrs.getString(1);
    }
} catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("db connection not connected");
}
```

Comment: You have to check the message of the exception. try `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`

Comment: not executing   mystmt.execute();

Comment: i am getting this error FUNCTION pandu_data.proc_pandu_check_user does not exist

Comment: i have database connection and all pls check above code but i am not able to get

Answer (score 0):

From what you say in your comments, you seems to be missing a sql function "proc_pandu_check_user".

Check the body of the "proc_hi_check_user", somewhere there it should call this proc_pandu_check_user and it is probably missing or has wrong argument list.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing below code:

```
try 
{   
    connection myconn = Database.Get_Connection();
    CallableStatement mystmt =null;
    mystmt = myconn.prepareCall("{? =call proc_hi_check_user(?,?)}");
    mystmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.OTHER);
    mystmt.setString(2,name);
    mystmt.setString(3,"");
    mystmt.execute();
    param1 = mystmt.getInt(1);
    ResultSet myrs = mystmt.getResultSet();
    while(myrs.next())
    {
        System.out.println("inside");
        System.out.println(myrs.getInt(1));
        //result=myrs.getString(1);
    }
} catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("db connection not connected");
}
```